# clang fails to parse the LR register from PowerPC

Tags: assembly, clang, cpu-registers, powerpc

code:

```
.globl main
main:
  mfspr 0, lr
```

the clang internal assembler thinks lr is a symbol, not a register:

```
$ clang --target=ppc32 regs.s -c; nm regs.o
         U lr
00000000 T main
```

anyone knows what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using `%lr`** results in `7c 08 02 a6   mflr 0` according to `llvm-objdump -d`, without an unresolved `lr` symbol.

`gcc -mregnames` compiling C to PPC asm uses names like `%r3`: https://godbolt.org/z/7dMnK74vc

Clang doesn't support that option; unless there's a similar option with a different name, clang's asm output always uses instructions like `add 3, 3, 4` with just numbers.  But I guess clang / LLVM's assembler supports the same "symbolic" register names that GAS does, and those names start with a `%`, presumably to distinguish them from symbols.  (The same way that starting with a digit means they can't be symbols.)